# Event on selection from dropdown

Tags: dropdown

```
    <select (change)="f1()">
<option value="a">Option1</option>
<option value="b">Option2</option>
</select>
```

lets say user selects option2 from dropdown, then f1() will be executed as value of dropdown has changed and i am listening to change event. now again users clicks on dropdown and selects option2, in this case value of dropdown is  not changed, so f1 is not executed. now i want f1 to be executed each time users selects some value from dropdown, no matter value has changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is using `onclick`, your `f1()` will fire each time you click the drop down.

here is an example

```
<select id="mySelect" onclick="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="2">2
  <option value="3">3
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var clicks = 0;
function myFunction() {
    clicks++;
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x + " Clicks" + clicks;
}
</script>
```